# Refreshing the list after persist causes: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization

After persisting my hotel entity to the backend (mysql) any next frontend client call to refresh the list of equipments (collection in hotel) runs into this error (even if i mark the collection to be fetched eager):

> failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session
>   was closed

Managed bean of the frontend (using JSF):

```
   public void save() {
        hotel.setHotelUser(loginBean.getLoggedInUser());
        hotel = hopAccess.persistHotel(hotel);
        addMessage("Hotel saved!");
    }
```

Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "hotel")
    public class Hotel {

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "con_hotel_equipment", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_hotel", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_lookup",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false) })
        private Set<LookUp> equipments = new HashSet<LookUp>();
```

Service:

```
    @Override
@Transactional(value = "transactionManagerHop", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Hotel persistHotel(Hotel hotel) {
    Hotel entity = emHop.merge(hotel);
    addToCache(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. You may be trying to fetch a collection (here `wizzardBean.hotel.equipments`) which is supposed to be initialized lazily on the Hibernate side. Use `FetchType.EAGER` which in turn is seriously discouraged, use appropriate fetch join(s) or use some vendor specific configurations (which I personally dislike).

Comment: Thanks but check my code - there i already fetch the collection eager.

Comment: Yes but it may be lurking somewhere else. The answer will be in the complete exception stack-trace being thrown.

Comment: Try adding the attribute `collectionType="java.util.ArrayList"` to the selectCheckboxMenu

Comment: This will cause a mapping issue since hotel.equipments is of type Set.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the entity has become detached from the persistence context, before refreshing the entity you need to ensure it is attached (eg. using entityManager.findById() or equivalent)

Comment: yeah i tought the same. so i tried reloading the entity after persisting  to db. but also this did not work. same error.

Comment: you need to reload just before doing the refresh, is that what you tried?

Comment: no i reloaded the hotel just after hotel = hopAccess.persistHotel(hotel);

Comment: That wont help as the entity is becoming detatched after the request finishes....try doing the reload just before the refresh in the same method

Comment: btw: the refresh only crashes for this one collection. if i take the jsf tag for this collection out everthing works fine - no matter how many times i save the hotel to the db.

Comment: the refresh will be done by the jsf framework implicitly while invoking the hotel.getEquipments() method (see jsf page). there is no chance to load the entity from db at that time.